# Adding page links to content that automatically convert to pretty permalinks?

Tags: permalinks

Is it possible to insert links in Wordpress's wysiwyg editor that will convert to pretty permalinks when enabled?

i.e. the links would be this without pretty permalinks:

/?p=13

But with permalinks on, it would become this:

/mypagename/

I'm thinking I'd have to use a shortcode to do that right? Something that would use the ID and wp_list_pages() for pages at least... just thinking about a way to get links in content to work when permalinks are on and off.

Thanks

osu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is example of simple shortcode that will take ID as argument and echo permalink for it:

```
function link_from_id($atts) {

    if( isset($atts['id']) )
        return get_permalink( (int)$atts['id'] );
}

add_shortcode('link', 'link_from_id');
```

Usage:

```
[link id=1]
```

PS by the way non-pretty permalinks will keep working just fine if you enable pretty mode later and, if I remember right, will be redirected to canonical pretty version.

Comment: Thanks for this Rarst, much appreciated - and you're right about non-pretty permalinks working in both contexts.